# Best way to show only search results from some webapplication?

Tags: search

I have created a page with a search result webpart. I would like to show only results from webapplication "archive.com". Also the site collections and websites inside this webapplication. Do I need to do something like this in the query:

```
{searchTerms} path:archive.com*
```

Answer (score 3):

You should rather have result source that would limit results in a web application, and later use that result source in all search result web parts.

Comment: which query do I need to use in the result source. Like my example?

Comment: You don't need to mention any path unless you filter on a specific site collection results. Just use `{?{searchTerms}}`

Comment: I think you do not understand me. I created a new result source. Inside this result source I would like to show only results from webapplication "archive.com". This result source is used in the global search center. So you will see there Everything, conversations, people, documents and my custom result source "Arhive". In my result source I have now: {SearchTerms} Path:http://archive.com. I was just wondering if this is OK or is there a better way?